# Using R, group data together based on two values in a table

Tags: r

I need to build a "profile" of a data set, showing the number of data entries that lie between two values. I have been able to achieve the result using the "group_by" function, however the resultant output is not in a format that I can use further down my workflow.  Here is that output:

[image: Example 1]

What I need, is something that looks like this:

[image: Example 2]

The "Data Count" column, I've not been able to populate but is there for illustration.

The code I am using is as follows;

```
library(formattable)
PML_Start = 0
PML_Max = 100000000
PML_Interval = 5000000 

Lower_Band <- currency(seq(PML_Start, PML_Max-PML_Interval, PML_Interval),digits=0)
Upper_Band <- currency(seq(PML_Start+PML_Interval,PML_Max,PML_Interval),digits = 0)

PML_Profile <- data.frame("Lower Band"=Lower_Band,"Upper Band"=Upper_Band,"Data Count")
```

I know cannot figure out how to further populate this table.  I gave this a go, but didn't really believe it would work.

```
PML_Profile <- Profiles_on_Data_Provided_26_9_17 %>%
  group_by (Lower_Band) %>%
  summarise("Premium" = sum(Profiles_on_Data_Provided_26_9_17$`Written Premium - Total`))
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use the `labels` argument in `cut`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `Error in currency(seq(PML_Start, PML_Max - PML_Interval, PML_Interval),  : 
  could not find function "currency"`

Comment: Hey Jimbou - you need the "formattable" package installed.